# Animation doesn't run after first click

Tags: android, android-emulator

The first time I open up my application in the emulator and click the image to run the animation nothing happens.  When I go back to the home menu and then back to my app, the animation runs without me clicking anything.  Subsequent clicks after this point run the animation as it was intended to run.  This is using 2.3.3 in the emulator.  I have not seen this issue using version 4.1.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02); 
    image2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    image1.setClickable(true);

    image1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

 public void onClick(View v) {

    Log.d("== My activity ===","OnClick is called");  // This gets logged on every click
    Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);

    image2.startAnimation(fade1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous activity exit animation is overriding your enter animation. Usually you have to stop/override those with:

```
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade1, R.anim.fade_in);
```